# Why Poskim don't work and write in groups?

Tags: halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, sanhedrin

At any given moment there are several leading (and hundreds of secondary) Rabbis and Poskim. Each one running his own Yeshivah, writing his books and issuing his own Psakim.

I understood that the very idea of the Sanhedrin(s) was exactly the opposite of that - to achieve universality and acceptability of the Psakim, coming out of a Beis Din and not from single Poskim.

I also recognize, that this pattern emerged already from the time of the Tannoyim when the Sanhedrin still theoretically existed - each Rabbi had his own school instead of teaming up and working together.

What theological or Hashkafic explanation might fit this phenomenon - what the Rabbis themselves think about it and how does Judaism benefit from it?

Comment: If you're asking why there is no longer a Sanhedrin, a nice summary can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_attempts_to_revive_the_Sanhedrin#The_dissolution_of_the_classical_Sanhedrin  If you're asking why Rabbonim don't consult with others or learn in groups, I think that premise is incorrect. Most Rabbonim do study in Yeshivas, learn Bechavrusa, ask others for their opinion, etc. The fact that a book is published under one authors' name doesn't mean others didn't study with him. You can just look at ShU"T: someone had to have asked the question for there to be an answer.

Comment: Good question.  I don't recall seeing books written by more than one rabbi.